# PHPUnit 5.7 (autoloaded) Class Not Found

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, psr-4

I am having trouble getting PHPUnit (Version 5.7) to find my Custom Framework classes. Any help would be appreciated as i've tried alsorts. When I run the tests it complains that the autoloaded class cannot be found.

```
{
"scripts": {
    "test": [
        "@clean",
        "@load",
        "@phpunit"
    ],
    "clean": "composer clear-cache",
    "load": "composer dump-autoload -o",
    "phpunit": "\"vendor/bin/phpunit\" --configuration phpunit.xml tests"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "AdoptableFramework\\": "src/",
      "AdoptableFramework\\Tests\\": "tests/",
      "AdoptableFramework\\Extend\\": "src/extend/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "matthiasmullie/minify": "^1.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.7"
}
```

}

This is what my phpunit.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/5.7/phpunit.xsd"
bootstrap="vendor\autoload.php"
backupGlobals="true"
beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="true"
beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true"
backupStaticAttributes="false"
cacheTokens="false"
colors="always"
convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
convertNoticesToExceptions="false"
convertWarningsToExceptions="false"
forceCoversAnnotation="false"
mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
processIsolation="false"
stopOnError="false"
stopOnFailure="false"
stopOnIncomplete="false"
stopOnSkipped="false"
stopOnRisky="false"

verbose="true">
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">src/AdoptableFramework</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="tests/code_coverage" 
showUncoveredFiles="true"/>
</logging>
</phpunit>
```

My folder structure looks like:

```
src
--AdoptableFramework
----Core
------Database.php tests
--databaseTest.php
--unitTestSuite.php
```

This is what my databaseTest.php looks like:

```
    <?php

namespace AdoptableFramework\Tests;

use AdoptableFramework\Core\Database;
use AdoptableFramework\Tests\unitTestSuite;

class DatabaseTest extends UnitTestSuite
{
    public function testDatabase()
    {
        $database = new Database();

        $this->assertEquals(null, $database);
    }
}

?>
```

This is my Database.php withint AdoptableFramework/Core.

```
<?

/**
* @link      https://www.pswebsolutions.co.uk/
* @author    Paul Sonny Cook <paul.cook@pswebsolutions.co.uk>
* @copyright 2017 P S Web Solutions Ltd
* @version   1.0.0
* @package   psAdoptables
**/

namespace AdoptableFramework\Core;

class Database
{
    public function __construct($host = null, $username = null, $password = null, $database = null) {
        $this->type = __CLASS__;

        if ($host || $username || $password || $database) {
            $this->connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
        } else {
            $this->connect();
        }
    }

    public function connect($host = DB_HOST, $username = DB_USER, $password = DB_PASS, $database = DB_DATABASE)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

?>
```

autoload_static.php class mappings:

I have looked into my autoload_static.php file and can see this:

```
'AdoptableFramework\\Core\\Database' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/AdoptableFramework/Core/Database.php',
        'AdoptableFramework\\Extend\\ExtendDatabase' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/AdoptableFramework/Extend/ExtendDatabase.php',
        'AdoptableFramework\\Game' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/src/AdoptableFramework/Game.php',
        'AdoptableFramework\\Tests\\DatabaseTest' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/tests/databaseTest.php',
        'AdoptableFramework\\Tests\\UnitTestSuite' => __DIR__ . '/../..' . '/tests/unitTestSuite.php',
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please also show us `Database.php` or at least the first few lines

Comment: I've added the Database.php class - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terribly sorry for wasting everyones time!

The php files were being loaded as text because it wanted

Once I changed everything clicked into place and started working!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your `src/AdoptableFramework` directory is not necessary. You can either remove it and move all files one level higher or try this use statement:

```
use AdoptableFramework\AdoptableFramework\Core\Database;
```

This line `"AdoptableFramework\\": "src/",` tells autoloader that any class in **src** folder is already in **AdoptableFramework** namespace. As an example, if you create class `Foo` this way `src/Foo.php` you will import it this way:

```
use AdoptableFramework\Foo;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help/suggestions but still throwing the same error. I have added my autoload_static.php to see the class mappings. I have this on BitBucket if it helps to look at it that way?

Comment: Bitbucket would help for sure, there is some issue with directories structure and autoloading, can't see any problem with the code itself.